# Keying an eager-loaded relationship

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have a Business model and an Hour model. The Business model overrides the `protected $with` method to eager load it's `hours() hasMany` relationship.

When I `::first()` a given business I receive something like this:

```
App\Business {#770
 id: 5,
 user_id: 5,
 name: "Wehner-Hudson",
 slug: "wehner-hudson",
 lat: "55.33593500",
 lng: "112.34818600",
 created_at: "2018-01-04 13:00:48",
 updated_at: "2018-01-04 13:00:48",
 hours: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#753
   all: [
     App\Hour {#802
       id: 13,
       business_id: 5,
       weekday_id: 3,
       open: 1,
       split_shift: 1,
     },
     App\Hour {#803
       id: 14,
       business_id: 5,
       weekday_id: 5,
       open: 0,
       split_shift: 1,
     },
     App\Hour {#804
       id: 15,
       business_id: 5,
       weekday_id: 2,
       open: 1,
       split_shift: 0,
     },
   ],
 },
},
],
}
```

I would like to key the `hours: Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#753` by `weekday_id` to facilitate processing on the client side. Something like this:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#763
all: [
1 => App\Hour {#796
 id: 1,
 business_id: 1,
 weekday_id: 1,
 open: 1,
 split_shift: 1,
},
5 => App\Hour {#767
 id: 2,
 business_id: 1,
 weekday_id: 5,
 open: 0,
 split_shift: 0,
},
2 => App\Hour {#765
 id: 3,
 business_id: 1,
 weekday_id: 2,
 open: 1,
 split_shift: 1,
},
],
}
```

I tried to use keyBy on the relationship in the Business model:

```
public function hours()
{
   return $this->hasMany(Hour::class)->keyBy('weekday_id'); 
}
```

But it is not working, as I believe that at that point the returned object is a builder, not a collection.

Answer (score 0):

Try to define an accessor, like this:

```
public function getHoursByWeekdayAttribute()
{
    return $this->hours->keyBy('weekday_id');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using groupby in your controller.

```
Business::with(['hours' => function($query){ $query->groupBy('weekend_id'); }])->get();
```